# LSTM not working in Keras embedding model

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a neural network that utilizes keras's embedding layer as an input into the model. The embeddings are generated by word2vec and then organized and input into the model via the embedding layer. I am very confident that this segment of my code works. When I run my model using a single dense layer, everything runs as expected and I get an accuracy of around 75% on validation. However, replacing the dense layer with an LSTM returns an accuracy of around 50, and for all epochs it does not change by even a decimal.

The code for the embeddings and model is below:

```
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=MAX_TOKENS, output_sequence_length=INPUT_LENGTH)
text_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_samples).batch(128)
vectorizer.adapt(text_ds)
voc = vectorizer.get_vocabulary()
word_index = dict(zip(voc, range(len(voc))))



tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(samples)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(samples)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index

embeddings_index = {}
f = open(os.path.join("Data/", 'model.csv'), encoding="latin-1")
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    try:
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    except ValueError:
        coefs = np.zeros(100,)
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()



embedding_dim = 100
hits = 0
misses = 0

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((MAX_TOKENS+2, embedding_dim))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # Words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        # This includes the representation for "padding" and "OOV"
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
        hits += 1
    else:
        misses += 1



x_train = vectorizer(np.array([[s] for s in train_samples])).numpy()
x_val = vectorizer(np.array([[s] for s in val_samples])).numpy()

y_train = np.array(train_labels).astype("float32")
y_val = np.array(val_labels).astype("float32")



model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_TOKENS+2, embedding_dim,  weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=INPUT_LENGTH, trainable=False))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
# Fit the model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=3,batch_size=32, verbose=2)
```

Comment: try adding an other layer of LSTM or bidirectional LSTM and make `return_sequences=True` . This way model learns the context more effectively.

Comment: `LSTM(32)` should recur 32 times, in case the sequences from your text has more than 32 words per sequence, that LSTM won't be able to learn it all

Comment: @datdinhquoc I see. I will try to change this now and check if that works.